# Как в цикле вывести определённое количество ссылок постраничной навигации

Tags: pagination, php

```
<table id="pagination">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php if(count($this->pages) != 1) { ?>
                <?php for ($i = 0; $i <count($this->pages); $i++) { ?>
                    <a href="<?=$this->pages[$i]?>"><?=($i + 1)?></a>&nbsp
                <?php }} ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

У меня выводятся все ссылки подряд, а мне нужно хотя бы чтоб вывелось 5 шт и открытая страница выделялась

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  <b>10</b>  11 12 13 14
```

Нужно вывести от активной по 2 шт по бокам и желательно ссылка на первую и последую страницу, то есть всего 7 ссылок а остальные скрыть. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: @jobananas, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю Вам воспользоваться готовым плагином валидации: `jquery.simplePagination.js`

Плагин имеет достаточный перечень настроек.

А что касается отображаемых данных и как их запрашивать, то сделайте подгрузку данных при помощь ajax запроса.

**Обновление**

HTML, в который вставится пагинация:

```
<div id="light-pagination" class="pagination"></div>
```

Подключаем `query.simplePagination.js`. Инициализация:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
        $('#light-pagination').pagination({
            items: arPagen.allElement,
            itemsOnPage: arPagen.countElementPage,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            currentPage: arPagen.currentPage,
            hrefTextPrefix: '?pagen=',
            prevText: 'Пред.',
            nextText: 'След.'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: у меня всё работает страницы листает, выводится всё чюдесно но вот с выводом самих кнопок бы разобратся.

Comment: а как подключается плагин в php код?

Comment: Cоздал файл query.simplePagination.js скопировал в него код:
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
        $('#light-pagination').pagination({
            items: arPagen.allElement,
            itemsOnPage: arPagen.countElementPage,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            currentPage: arPagen.currentPage,
            hrefTextPrefix: '?pagen=',
            prevText: 'Пред.',
            nextText: 'След.'
        });
    });
});

подключил файл к html документу, потом вставил <div id="light-pagination" class="pagination"></div> в html документ.

И ничего неотображаетс

Comment: Это готовый плагин jQuery, его надо скачать и подключить в своем приложении.
Плагин скачивается от сюда: http://plugins.jquery.com/simple-pagination/

И почитайте про то, как подключать и использовать скрипты. Я тут Вам не смогу рассказать курс по взаимодействию PHP+JS+AJAX

Comment: а можно используя выходные данные которые у меня есть не используя плагина самому вывести определённые кнопки навигации?
У меня есть количество страниц, у меня есть количество вывода на 1ной странице,у меня есть текущая страница в переменной, просто нужно вывести кнопки навигации в таком формате, нет правда переменной с количеством кнопок навигации, формат такого плана: 
    Первая страница     Предыдущая страница     4   5   6   8   9   Следующая страница  Последняя страница

Comment: данные подгружаюстя и сортируются просто мне нужно правильно показать кнопки навигации у меня выводятся вот так 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 и тд.а мне нужно так:
Первая страница Предыдущая страница 4 5 6 8 9 Следующая страница Последняя страница

Answer (score 1):

В двух словах. В твоем цикле(for) возьми диапазон от ($выбраннаяСтраница - 5) до ($выбраннаяСтраница + 5).

Внутри цикла поставь проверку, если $i отрицательное или больше общего кол-ва страниц то continue. Таким образом ты отрисуешь нужные тебе страницы, за минусом не существующих, но не более 11(1 страница это выбранная, 10 диапазон).

Ну и если $i == номер выбранной страницы, то обрамление в bold.

Пример моего кода, правда тяжелый для чтения, но логика по идее должна быть тебе понятной.

```
    if ($_pages["total_pages"] > 1){
        if ($_pages["selected_page"] > 1){
            $_pages["html_pages"] .= " <a href='".$array["module_link"]."?_page".$array["page_prefix"]."=1&_per_page=".$array["per_page"].$array["html_link"]."'>1</a> ";       
            $_pages["html_pages"] .= " <a href='".$array["module_link"]."?_page".$array["page_prefix"]."=".($_pages["selected_page"]-1)."&_per_page=".$array["per_page"].$array["html_link"]."'>&laquo;</a> ";
            $_pages["html_pages"] .= "<strong>...</strong>";
        }
        for ($i=$_pages["selected_page"]-15;$i<=$_pages["selected_page"]+15;$i++){
            if ($i<=0 || $i>$_pages["total_pages"]) continue;

            if ($i == $_pages["selected_page"]) 
                $_pages["html_pages"] .=    " <span> $i </span>";           
            else
                $_pages["html_pages"] .= " <a href='".$array["module_link"]."?_page".$array["page_prefix"]."=".$i."&_per_page=".$array["per_page"].$array["html_link"]."'>$i</a> ";

        }
        if ($_pages["selected_page"] < $_pages["total_pages"]){
            $_pages["html_pages"] .= "<strong>...</strong>";
            $_pages["html_pages"] .= " <a href='".$array["module_link"]."?_page".$array["page_prefix"]."=".($_pages["selected_page"]+1)."&_per_page=".$array["per_page"].$array["html_link"]."'>&raquo;</a> ";
            $_pages["html_pages"] .= " <a href='".$array["module_link"]."?_page".$array["page_prefix"]."=".$_pages["total_pages"]."&_per_page=".$array["per_page"].$array["html_link"]."'>".$_pages["total_pages"]."</a> ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: ок потестю чють позже отвечу спс за содержательный ответ

Comment: а с моим выводом как оно должно выглядить?

Comment:     Первая страница  Предыдущая страница  4  5  6  8  9  Следующая страница  Последняя страница

Comment: 6 кнопка должна быть активной как мне сделать такой вывод ссылок навигации?

Answer (score 0):

```
private function pagination($page, $count_pages) {
    // $back - ссылка НАЗАД
    // $forward - ссылка ВПЕРЁД
    // $startpage - ссылка ВНАЧАЛО
    // $endpage - ссылка ВКОНЕЦ
    // $page2left - вторая страница слева
    // $page1left - первая страница слева
    // $page2right - вторая страница справа
    // $page1right - первая страница справа

    $uri = "?";
    // если есть параметры в адресной строке
    if( !isset($page) ) $page = 1;
    if( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ){
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
            if( $key != 'page' ) $uri .= "{$key}=$value&amp;";
        }
    }

    if( $page > 1 ) {
        $back = "<a class='nav-link' href='{$uri}page=".($page-1)."'>&lt;</a>";
    }

    if( $page < $count_pages ) {
        $forward = "<a class='nav-link' href='{$uri}page=".($page+1)."'>&gt;</a>";
    }

    if( $page > 3 ) {
        $startpage = "<a class='nav-link' href='{$uri}page=1'>&laquo;</a>";
    }

    if( $page < ($count_pages -2) ) {
        $endpage = "<a class='nav-link' href='{$uri}page=".$count_pages."'>&raquo;</a>";
    }

    if( $page - 2 > 0 ) {
        $page2left = "<a class='nav-link' href='{$uri}page=".($page-2)."'>".($page-2)."</a>";
    }

    if( $page - 1 > 0 ) {
        $page1left = "<a class='nav-link' href='{$uri}page=".($page-1)."'>".($page-1)."</a>";
    }

    if( $page + 1 <= $count_pages ) {
        $page1right = "<a class='nav-link' href='{$uri}page=".($page+1)."'>".($page+1)."</a>";
    }

    if( $page + 2 <= $count_pages ) {
        $page2right = "<a class='nav-link' href='{$uri}page=".($page+2)."'>".($page+2)."</a>";
    }

    return $startpage.$back.$page2left.$page1left.'<a class="nav-active">'.$page.'</a>'.$page1right.$page2right.$forward.$endpage;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Вопрос прошу щитать закрытым выход найден, вот то што мне нужно было

Comment: $page - активная страница
$count_pages - колисчество страниц
вариируя 2мя этими параметрами получил нужный результат при выводе!

Comment: @jobananas Молодцы, что разобрались. Правда, Ваше решение вышло слишком завязанным на html. Никогда не мешайте бизнес-логику вашего приложения с представлением.

Comment: это вывод ссылок постраничной навигации,в зависимости от условий а логика в других функциях

Comment: <?php if($this->count != 1) {?>
<div id="pagination">
 <?=$this->paginas?>
</div>
<?php } ?>

Comment: вот весь вывод в этой строке заключон, а в функции выше описаны,условия вывода ссылок

Comment: > это вывод ссылок постраничной навигации а логика в других функциях

@jobananas, Вы ошибаетесь. Вот пример, как [надо делать](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-helpers/blob/master/src/Pagination.php). На выходе получаем массив: перечень страниц, активная страница, первая, последняя и т.д. Последний достаточно вставить в шаблон и никаких вычислений в шаблоне.